# After installing magento 2.3 Content is not loaded Properly also get console error 404 js and css not found

Tags: installation, magento2.3.1, page-content

Magento 2.3.1 i have install but in browser i have found that content ins not loaded properly and in console i have found multiple Error of Js and CSS is not found (404 js not found / css not found )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found Solution of it
Go to

> vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php

Find line

> $realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);

and Replace With

> $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));

and also run all the commands